# background image responsive blank space when resize screen

Tags: css

I use following css:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
background:url(Top.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center top;
min-height:800px;
```

I have responsive background image when screen size change, but I have a problem with blank space around the responsive background image when screen size become smaller than min-height. I want when screen become smaller than min-height the height of div change automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size: cover` instead.

```
background: ("Top.jpg") no-repeat center top fixed;
background-size: cover;
/* For older browsers */
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
min-height:800px;
```

See https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: I can not use background-size: cover; I want background height become small when screen is small and ..